# An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occured in 'System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I have just started working on c#.net. below is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=register;Integrated Security=True");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

private const string strconneciton = "Data Source=ADMIN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=register;Integrated Security=True";

SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strconneciton);

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     con.Open();
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into user(uname, address, 
email, number) values('" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + TextBox2.Text + "', '" + 
TextBox3.Text + "', '" +TextBox4.Text+ "')", con);

     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     con.Close();
 }
}
```

and I am getting this error

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occured in 'System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

please help. I am using microsoft sql server management studio.

Comment: using System.Data; import this.

Comment: You can try using a `try - catch` block to get the exception which might give you more details about the error. *Edit: There are couple of things you can improve as well. Try searching for `parameterized queries` and `using` statements for your connection and `SqlCommand`

Comment: Copy your sqlcommand to directly MSSQL query, execute it with values and see if there will be an error about this command.

Comment: Stop using plaintext queries, use parameterization. obviously that will solve your issues as well

Comment: Are you sure they all accept string (varchar, nvarchar, etc) values?

Comment: yes all accept varchar@mindAi

Comment: I tried this query insert into user ('uname', 'address', 'email', 'number') 
values
('nirmala', 'pune', 'nirmala@gmail.com', '8989898'); got this error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword user" @ReadyFreddy

Comment: Issue resolved thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Parameters function to add values to your command strings, always. I think it's problem about you are sending value "number" as char and you may define it as int at your database. So you can try to delete single qutoes from `Textbox4.Text`.

But if you want to make it better, use parameters. Like that.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into user(uname, address, 
email, number) values(@uname,@address,@email,@number)", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", TextBox1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBox2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox3.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", TextBox4.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This will also prevent any SQL Injection problems.

Comment: You are right: the problem is in the `number`, but the reason is *different*: it's MS Sql's *reserved word* and that's why should be *wrapped in brackets*: `"...[number]..."`

Comment: I tried changing table name and its working I think 'user' is a keyword in MSSQL so it was showing error 'Incorrect syntax at at keyword user' @ReadyFreddy thank you

Comment: No problem. Can you just tick my or other answer (it's more useful btw) to let people know there is a solution of this problem? Thank you. Ow solution is not what we said okey :) so please inform people by editing your question.

Answer (score 2):

Do not *hardcode* sql queries:

1. They are *difficult to read* (so you can easily commit *syntax error*: in your case `number` is MS Sql's **reserved word** and should be put as `[number]`)
2. They are prone to errors (e.g. what if `TextBox2.Text` contains an *apostroph*, `'`)
3. They are vulnerable to *Sql Injection*

I suggest extracting a method:

```
private void CoreInsert() {
  //Done: wrap IDisposable into using, do not close explicitly
  //TODO: do not hardcode strConnection, but read from settings
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection)) {
    con.Open();

    // Make sql 
    //   1. Readable: can you see a problem with "Number" now? 
    //   2. Parametrized 
    string sql = 
      @"insert into [user](
          uname, 
          address, 
          email, 
          [number]) -- <- number is MS SQL's reserved word, put it as [number]
        values(
          @prm_uname, 
          @prm_address, 
          @prm_email, 
          @prm_number)";

    //Done: wrap IDisposable into using
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_uname", TextBox1.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_address", TextBox2.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_email", TextBox3.Text);
      //TODO: check actual field's type here 
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prm_number", TextBox4.Text);

      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }    
  }
}
```

Then call the method

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  CoreInsert();
}
```